# Minify HTML files in text/html templates

Tags: sed, mustache, handlebars.js, yui-compressor, http-compression

I use mustache/handlebar templates.

eg:

```
<script id="contact-detail-template" type="text/html">
    <div>... content to be compressed </div>
</script>
```

I am looking to compress/minify my HTML files in the templates for the best compression.

YUIcompressor, closure does not work as they think that it is script and gives me script errors.

HTMLCompressor does not touch them even as it thinks that it is a script.

How do I minify the content in the script tags with type text/html?
Can I use a library?
If not, is sed or egrep a preferable way? Do you have sed/egrep syntax to remove empty lines (with just spaces or tabs), remove all tabs, trim extra spaces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//g" -e "/^$/d" yourfile` This will remove all the extra spaces and tabs from the begining, and remove all empty lines.

`sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//g" -e ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g" yourfile` This will remove all the extra spaces and tabs from the begining, and concatenate all your code.

Sorry if i missed something.

Comment: If you are not on Windows, change from double quotes, to single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. It's close but it does not remove the tabs. After some research, I figured out that \t does not work. You should do a ctrl+v and then hit a tab on the command line. Putting in script, you should hit a tab instead of \t. It worked otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: on mac iterm2, when i copy and paste on terminal its not working
`sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//g" -e ":a;N;$basename utility.js;s/\n//g"` 
also its not working on mac terminal

Comment: @indianwebdevil you may need to wrap the commands with single quotes instead of double quotes.  The ! character is likely getting involved with your zsh/mac command history.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/>\s*</></g' file`, it enables to you *remove whitespaces and newlines* where **unneeded**. Unlike ghaschel example, this **doesn't remove those useful whitespaces** in the beginning of the line as it preserves `<pre>` and `<p>` tags.

This is useful as you can remove whitespaces between `>` and `<` which is a common method to **enlarge** a html file. This example could also be used for a **XML file** like *atom feed* and *rss feed* for example.

I personally use this as a pipe in my [site generator](http://git.pickfire.wha.la/www), this can reduce a normaly file size and [can be use in conjunction with `gzip`](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-minification-and-gzipping/).

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify) to minify this kind of code.  It will only assume the stuff inside script tags is JavaScript if there is no mime type or if the type is one of the various JavaScript types.  It is also intelligent enough to know which white space is okay to remove without corrupting the output of content or the recursive beautification of code later.

Comment: Thank you. The tool is promising but lacks a simple command-like-tool - minify.sh etc. The other tools like htmlcompressor, yui are fairly simple to use. 'Pretty diff' is simple if we are using it in a node.js app but is very convoluted if used in normal apps. You have to build a maven-kind of script and then execute. I prefer sed to this Pretty Diff if removing tabs/spaces is the purpose.

Comment: It offers native command line support in Windows using WSH.  Please see http://prettydiff.com/prettydiff.wsf as the api to WSH.  I am currently working on an extension to allow directory and subdirectory comparisons opposed to mere file comparisons.  For other systems I do offer some support for Node.js using a file api.js.  The Node.js support is a bit dated and I plan to update this soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using mac. I would suggest you add a .jar if possible which can be run as a .sh. If not, a custom .sh would be good for unix users. I love this library and look forward to using it when I have access to .sh files.

Comment: To my knowledge Bash shell does not offer interpretation of JavaScript and current distributions of Unix and Linux do not offer JavaScript interpretation like the way they offer a Perl interpreter.  In this case you would have to install an additional program, such as Node.js.  I do not have a lot of experience with Mac, so I can be entirely wrong.